# Figuring out an equation to reduce two numbers to a single less than 10 value and back again

Tags: algorithm, math, equation

Ok so lets say i have the two numbers 183 and 85. Is there a way, some kind of formula that i could use on these or any two numbers that would reduce them down to a single combined digit that is less than 10 that i could then send to a location and re construct BACK into my original two numbers once its gets there? So for example :

183 and 85 reduce down to 9, i then send the number 9 and reverse the process?.

I am trying to figure out a way to do this that could be used on ANY two numbers i chose and they would still reconstruct once they were received on the other side

Maths is not my strong point if I'm honest, i can do basic math and i am starting to study maths again but this is way over my head. BUT, i would like to figure out an answer as I'm curious

Comment: just a note, 183 and 85 do not necessarily reduce to 9 that was just as an example

Comment: I will say this also, its kind of annoying that people down vote a serious question. It just seems rude is all. Maths is not my strong point and i was asking this genuinely.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you may like to read the site tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour. In particular it says "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." At the moment the question reads like an impossible math puzzle and not an "actual problem you have faced." Perhaps if you write the problem you were actually trying to solve when you thought of this idea as a solution, and you'll have better luck with getting your questions upvoted, as well as getting useful answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 4):

No.

This would throw the [information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) out the window.

There are 10 single digit integers, from 0 to 9. Therefore there are 10 things that single digit integers can represent. It's as simple as that.